# Is it possible to have on service check multiple hosts on nagios

Tags: nagios, snmp

I have a few hosts that check for the temperature through snmp, and I was wondering if I could combine the 4 different services into one service that checks all 4 hosts temperatures. I know that they have different OID's, but I was hoping there was a way to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a check do anything you can program. The only thing you need to do is craft the output of your check such that Nagios can parse it. In this specific case, I might implement this as a passive check.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the stock [check_snmp](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_snmp) plugin, you can check all 4 temperatures at once. See the first note in the *--help* output:

> - Multiple OIDs (and labels) may be indicated by a comma or space-delimited
>     list (lists with internal spaces must be quoted). Maximum: 8 OIDs.

If you're using some other plugin, like a custom variant of check_snmp, this is a perfect use case for [check_multi](http://my-plugin.de/wiki/projects/check_multi/start).